# Change/increment title of td with for loop - JQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, title, html-table

I need to assign numbers to my table cells, which increment from cell to cell. I have tried a forloop but am having trouble assigning the incremented counter to the cell's title after each loop. I have this code -

```
$(function(){
var row = $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat')
for(i=0; i<row.length; i++){
        row.attr('title', i);   
    }
});
```

This code only assigns the final value of i after the loop has completed, to all the cells' titles... Instead of assigning '1, 2, 3' etc to the titles. I should perhaps add that the table is dynamically generated using jquery also. Apologies for the vague title and description - I tried my best!

Thanks

Comment: wats else doing in for loop..?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use `.each()` anyway

```
var row = $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat');
$.each(row, function(index){
    $(this).attr('title', index+1);
});
```

But actually, you would do it straight from the selector.

```
$('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('title', index+1);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Don't have enough rep to upvote unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

> *"This code only assigns the final value of i after the loop has completed, to all the cells' titles"*

That's because on each iteration you're setting the attribute of every matching element. (`row.attr('title',i)` operates on every element in the `row` jQuery object.)

If you're using jQuery you'll find it simpler to use its [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) rather than a conventional `for` loop:

```
$(function(){
    var rows = $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat');
    rows.each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('title',i);
    });
});
```

Unless you use it for something else later you don't then need the `rows` variable at all:

```
$(function(){
    $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat').each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('title',i);
    });
});
```

But to do it with a `for` loop you could use the [`eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get access the curret item:

```
$(function(){
    var row = $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat')
    for(i=0; i<row.length; i++){
        row.eq(i).attr('title', i);   
    }
});
```

Any of these methods will start with `i` at `0`, so use `i+1` if you want the displayed numbering to start with `1`.

Comment: We posted identical answers a few seconds apart. +1

Comment: @popnoodles - If you mean the `i + 1` thing I've added a note about it, thanks. (Originally I figured the OP would sort that part out - the key problem was accessing the individual cells.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function of jquery

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('title', index+1)
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KX5xL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   var row = $(document).children('#seat_map tr:last').find('td.freeSeat');
   for(i=0; i<row.length; i++){
      row.attr('title', i);   
   }
});
```

or this:

```
$(function(){
   var row = $('#seat_map tr:last td.freeSeat', this);
   for(i=0; i<row.length; i++){
      row.attr('title', i);   
   }
});
```

As you mentioned *`I should perhaps add that the table is dynamically generated using jquery`*